# Send SMS with Huawei Dongle

Tags: raspberry-pi, sms, raspberry-pi3, dongle

I have Raspberry Pi 3 and Huawei Dongle and SIM Card (attached screenshot)
My SIM Card working find and send SMS well from Smartphone.
I'm trying to send SMS from the Raspberry, i follow this tutorial (https://learnaddict.com/2018/02/17/send ... gsm-board/) and i'm getting an Error ("No response in specified timeout. Probably the phone is not connected")
I googled it a lot to find a soultion to this problem, but nothing help

[image: 1. My devices]
[image: 2. The ifconfig]
[image: 3. The Gumma config]
[image: 4. The Error]

1. My devices
2. The ifconfig
3. The Gumma config
4. The Error

Answer (score 0):

U can't set PORT on HiLink, try this:
[Sending and receiving SMS by command line with Huawei E3131 and HiLink on a debian system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016641/sending-and-receiving-sms-by-command-line-with-huawei-e3131-and-hilink-on-a-debi)
It work with Huawei 3372h.
Probably u need to change session and token link.

Comment: Error 125003 it's a bad link to get token, i have no problem on: http://192.168.8.1/html/index.html